# Finding databases with same columns and different content/ model

Tags: dataset

I am looking for datasets that have the same columns and their content (rows) are different. When I run a decision tree (classification) I'll get different models (trees) for each of them. It can be data of customers of different bank or insurance companies.

Just for clarification the datasets should have the following criteria:

```
1. Have same columns
2. Categorized target column (i.e. I can build decision tree)
3. Each dataset can have enough data (over 1000 tuples)
4. The decision trees that I create (2) from each dataset is different
```

Comment: Are you looking for databases where the data is stored differently between the two databases? If not, you could theoretically split a single database into 2 smaller ones randomly.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Barry. I already thought of your great idea. However, I'm looking for 2 or more different sources of databases since their origin plays an important role in the processing. If for instance I'll have same structure of data from different banks for instance it would be helpful. I looked in UCI datasets repository and didn't find. If you can help me I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, that was my only thought, hopefully others can help.

Comment: Are these SQL or NoSQL databases? Is the question on collecting the data, or on the analysis of the data?

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I am looking for SQL databases (with columns). I would like to use them for analysis but the question is about the data itself. I need about 6 databases (each can be at least 2000 tuples) of different companies such as banks with same columns. No matter the column names only they have to be the same. The databases should be with target column. So that I'll be able to create a decision tree for each.

Comment: It's probably the terminology of my background (database programming) that is giving me difficulty in understanding what you are after. 

I can give you the SQL statements to find out MS SQL Server schema structure (e.g.), but it sounds like you actually want a number of database schemas for similar subject areas to test your decision trees on. I guess this might mean approaching a number of similar companies and ask them to run the same code on a similar. I would suggest Lloyds syndicates as there are hundreds of them that will be storing quite similar data.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, What I actually need is the data not the schema nor the structure. Pure data of 6 different companies in the same branch. That the data has same columns. Something like datasets in UCI repository. Lloyds syndicates is a great source if they can send me a data for number of different brokers that can fit a classification model such as decision tree. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I think you would be hard pressed to get companies to give you their data, unless it was anonymised, but even then, they might be concerned about pricing and confidential information that could be gleaned from it.

Comment: How about data from the same source but different years?

Comment: Thanks Kyler, the point in the process I use is the source of data. Time is has less importance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to build classifier on similar entities taken from different distributions and than compare the classifier/source distributions. Am I right?

By the way, if it is indeed so you might find the area of [domain adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_adaptation)

In this case I would go in your direction of splitting a database (since you need the same entities and features). In order the splitting will make sense I recommend doing the splitting by a feature that should change the entities behavior (e.g., country, far periods in time). That dataset you should use must be quite large in order to have large enough partitioned datasets.

Specific such dataset that you might find useful are [US census 2000](http://www.census.gov/main/www/cen2000.html) (plenty of options for concept and splitting features).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. Can you specify directly the link of data itself in  US census 2000?

Comment: There are many aspect of the census you can get. An example to the demographic data is in here http://www2.census.gov/census_2000/datasets/100_and_sample_profile/ . I didn't work with this dataset myself before. The files I saw now are pdf summaries and I cannot download the zip files (hopefully raw data) so this specific case might not be good. Was I right about the goal? Is such type of dataset fit your needs?

Comment: Thanks a lot. About my goal - is there a way I can discuss it with you personally?

Comment: levind4 at gmail

Comment: I didn't find the required datasets in US census.

Comment: Take a look at the question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197238/synthetic-datasets-for-concept-drifting-data It is about concept drifting but the datasets (partitioned by time) might be helpful for you too.

Comment: Thanks Dan, The datasets that are in the question you suggested are not numeric data and are not in column format.

Comment: See this site on data sets http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I hope this [data set might](http://www.modelingonlineauctions.com/datasets) suits you.This contains details of eBay Online Auctions (2012). very similar to your bank customer database you looking for. And all CSV format. Therefore you can import it to SQL also.Just Tryout.

**File Format**

> All files are available in comma separated format (CSV).

This dataset contain details of:

**Data Field Description**

> *auctionid* - unique identifier of an auction
>
> *bid* - the proxy bid placed by a bidder
>
> *bidtime* - the time (in days) that the bid was placed, from the start of the auction
>
> *bidder* - eBay username of the bidder
>
> *bidderrate* - eBay feedback rating of the bidder
>
> openbid - the opening bid set by the seller
>
> *price* - the closing price that the item sold for (equivalent to the second highest bid + an increment)

**Or** 
My personal favorite [Google Adwords dataset](https://code.google.com/archive/p/open-advertising-dataset/downloads). You need to really check it to know how much information it has...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miller. Can you please explain how can I find the relevant 'banks' in the dataset? I mean different 'organizations' that behaves differently (i.e. has different models). Can you please explain how can I find the criteria (1) to (4) mentioned in my question (what is the target - price?) Did someone build a different decision tree with this database for each 'orgaznization'?